# MPMoviePlayerController for remote file on Amazon S3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

My app allows videos to be displayed in UITableViewCells on iOS.

I'm currently storing my video files in Amazon S3 and utilizing Cloudfront.  I got this code from the Apple docs:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =

        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];

[player prepareToPlay];

[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's

[myView addSubview: player.view];

// ...

[player play];
```

I have implemented this code pretty much exactly into my own app.  For some reason, it does not seem to work for me. I think it may have something to do with not having JWPlayer installed in my S3 bucket.

My question is: In order to display a video in the app that allows playing while loading the remaining contents of the video in the background, do I need to have JWPlayer in my S3 bucket?...or is this unnecessary given the use of MPMoviePlayerController.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you test `myURL` if is the right one and if it's working from browser ?

Comment: Yup, it gives me a link to download the file.  The file plays once downloaded...

Comment: Is your content encoded as an M3U8 HTTP stream (that is, a few M3U8 profile files and a large number of TS chunk files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that the `MPMoviePlayerController` can't play that file because is not streamed. `[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];` expects a network stream, in your case is not a network stream. What you could do, is download the file and save it in your app documents files and play it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually want to stream the files in order to reduce costs.  I set my Cloudfront account to allow streaming...however, the video still does not play.

Comment: @user2312407 you have to check it in the browser, if it's streaming in the browser than you know that the problem is in your code. But form your code snippet everything should work ok if the video is properly configured on the server side. You should try to play a youtube video or other streamed video from web just to check your code.

Comment: Thanks danypata.  There was indeed a problem with my data.  Also, I found a good tutorial that seemed to help set everything up properly: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_6_iPhone_Application